# NextJS throws random "Error: Cannot find module './undefined'"

Tags: next.js

I just encountered this error while navigating to different links using NextJs's Link Component; Once this error showed up, I couldn't access any pages until I restarted the npm run build command, and everything worked properly again.

However, I can't figure out what caused this error and I wanted to make sure this doesn't happen in my production app. Does anyone have an idea what might have caused this error?

```
Error: Cannot find module './undefined'
Require stack:
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/.next/server/pages/_document.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/output/store.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/output/index.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at mod._resolveFilename (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/require-hook.js:183:28)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at __webpack_require__.f.require (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:233:28)
    at /Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:160:40
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at __webpack_require__.e (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:159:67)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/.next/server/pages/_document.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/output/store.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/output/index.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/GitHub/scraft/scraft-app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'
  ]
}
error - Error: Cannot find module './undefined'
```

[image]

Comment: i have exactly the same problem. have you perhaps already found a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I just had the exact same problem just before first time in production.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to import a page called `undefined` in `/pages/_document.js`, which I imagine isn't what you really want to do.

Can you add your `_document` page import code?

Comment: I actually do not have _document.js in my pages directory. I only have index.tsx